# How to change the net-snmp trap sender port in linux?

Tags: linux, snmp, net-snmp

I'm using the net-snmp for gather system information in linux.
but I found there is problem.

when I check port usage of Net-SNMP by netstat, I found net-snmp using 3 UDP port.

Here is the result.

```
[root@ snmp]# netstat -anp | grep snmp

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:199               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      6392/snmpd          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:49005               0.0.0.0:*                               6392/snmpd          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:161                 0.0.0.0:*                               6392/snmpd          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:44837               0.0.0.0:*                               6392/snmpd
```

as you can see, the snmpd using 2 more udp port without 161.
also I found why the 2 udp ports are randomly occupied by snmp.

those ports are using for sending snmp trap.
when I remove the tran2sink and informsink option, the 2 UDP ports are no more appear.

this is my part of configuration of snmpd.conf

```
###########################################################################
# SECTION: Trap Destinations
#
#   Here we define who the agent will send traps to.

# trap2sink: A SNMPv2c trap receiver
#   arguments: host [community] [portnum]

trap2sink  192.168.1.4  

# informsink: A SNMPv2c inform (acknowledged trap) receiver
#   arguments: host [community] [portnum]

informsink  192.168.1.4 NMS_COM 

# trapcommunity: Default trap sink community to use
#   arguments: community-string

trapcommunity  NMS_COM

# authtrapenable: Should we send traps when authentication failures occur
#   arguments: 1 | 2   (1 = yes, 2 = no)

authtrapenable  1
```

my program have to use 40000~50000 udp port.
so I want to use those trap options and change the ports.

how can I fix the ports?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set port for the directives as below:
trap2sink 1.1.1.1:port_num e.g. `trap2sink 1.1.1.1:162`

I hope I understood your question and this would help.

Answer (score 0):

These are SNMP Ephemeral ports. Here is a quote from a [Microsoft support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2514584) on them:

> While SNMP service is running it may be noticed via the netstat
>   Command Line utility that in addition to the well known ports for
>   sending and receiving SNMP traps (161/162) that a random ephemeral
>   port has been created by the service as well.
>
> The random port usage is intended behavior and is opened for the
>   purpose of sending "management" traps

...

> This port will remain in
>   the system while the SNMP service is running, but is not actively used
>   unless a management trap is to be sent outbound.  Since SNMP does not
>   listen for inbound packets on this random port, this does not present
>   a security vulnerability.